# how to enable kubelet logging verbosity

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet

I want to set higher logging verbosity in my k8s setup. While i managed to enable verbosity for API server and Kubectl by `--v=4` argument; I am having difficulties finding way to pass in this flag to Kubelet.

I am using `kubeadm init` method to launch small scale cluster, where master is also tainted so it can serve as minion. can you help in in enabling kubelet logging verbosity ?

Comment: following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52416671/kubelet-configuration will update upon log validation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) ssh to the master node

2) append `/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env` file with `--v=4`, i.e.

```
KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS=--cgroup-driver=cgroupfs --network-plugin=cni --pod-infra-container-image=k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1 --v=4
```

3) restart kubelet service

```
sudo systemctl restart kubelet
```

Comment: thank you for your response @A_suh ; I am attempting logging level 9 to get details on all http requests from kubelet . I have started doing exactly same steps after https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52416671/kubelet-configuration last night. I still have a huge log to go thorugh and i will report in a day if it worked or not.

Comment: yes these steps enable kubelet logging to desired level